# Closed form expression for an infinite series of Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, bessel-functions

I'm wondering how I might go about finding a closed form expression (if it exists) for the following infinite series containing modified Bessel functions:

$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}cos(n\theta)\ I_n(|x|) \left[K_n(|y|)\ -\ \frac{K_n(a)}{I_n(a)}I_n(|y|)\right]$

where $|x| < |y| < a$ and $cos(\theta) = \frac{x \cdot y}{|x||y|}$. I'm aware of the following addition theorems for (modified) Bessel functions:

$I_0\left(\sqrt{|x|^2 + |y|^2 - 2|x||y|cos(\theta)}\ \right) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}cos(n\theta)\ I_n(|x|)\ I_n(|y|)$
$K_0\left(\sqrt{|x|^2 + |y|^2 - 2|x||y|cos(\theta)}\ \right) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}cos(n\theta)\ I_n(|x|)\ K_n(|y|)$

so it's really the $\frac{K_n(a)}{I_n(a)}$ multiplicative factor in the second term of the series that makes this non-trivial.

Comment: I think you can strip out the $K_n(|y|)$ and the minus sign and the $2\pi$ from the question, for everybody else's purposes. That is I think it's enough for us to just look at $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \cos(n\theta) \frac{I_n(|x|)I_n(|y|) K_n(a)}{I_n(a)}$. If we can make that work then you can put it back in (and I don't think there is any $\infty - \infty$ issue, either).

Comment: Yes good point. I included the $K_n(|y|)$ term because it appears $K_n(|y|) I_n(a) - K_n(a) I_n(|y|)$ has some special relevance in the Bessel literature (I think it's called a Bessel cross product?), so it might be useful in simplifying the series. I removed the $2\pi$

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of writing it as $\frac{I_n(|x|)}{I_n(a)} \left ( K_n(|y|) I_n(a) - K_n(a) I_n(|y|) \right )$? I don't remember seeing that exact form, though. Usually these Wronskians have some variation in orders.